# python re.findall weird behaviour

Tags: python, regex, findall

```
>>> text =\
... """xyxyxy testmatch0
... xyxyxy testmatch1
... xyxyxy
... whyisthismatched1
... xyxyxy testmatch2
...  xyxyxy testmatch3
... xyxyxy
... whyisthismatched2
... """
>>> re.findall("^\s*xyxyxy\s+([a-z0-9]+).*$", text, re.MULTILINE)
[u'testmatch0', u'testmatch1', u'whyisthismatched1', u'testmatch2', u'testmatch3', u'whyisthismatched2']
```

So my expectations would be to not match the lines containing "whyisthismatched".

The Python re documentation states the following:

> (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a
>   newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any
>   character including a newline.

My question would be if this is really the expected behaviour or a bug.
If it is expected someone please explain why those lines are matching and how I should modify my pattern to get the behaviour I expect:

```
[u'testmatch0', u'testmatch1', u'testmatch2', u'testmatch3']
```

Comment: newline may be included in \s with re.MULTILINE ...  I think at least

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Newlines are whitespace too as far as the `\s` character class is concerned. If you want to match *spaces* only you need to match `[ ]` instead:

```
>>> re.findall("^\s*xyxyxy[ ]+([a-z0-9]+).*$", text, re.MULTILINE)
[u'testmatch0', u'testmatch1', u'testmatch2', u'testmatch3']
```

Comment: bah your faster :P as always (thanks for the info on my answer :)  )